# It is necessary to change the static method to make it Generic

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = GenericStatic.<Number>someStaticMethod(new Integer(3));
    }
}
```

_

```
public class GenericStatic {
    public static Object someStaticMethod(Object genericObject) {
        System.out.println(genericObject);
        return genericObject;
    }
}
```

Please help, how to do this? This is an exercise, but i cant understund...(

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Take a look at the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Specifically, the [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can make your static method generic:

```
public static <T> T someStaticMethod(T genericObject) {
    System.out.println(genericObject);
    return genericObject;
}
```